# Auth in chrome extension with supabase

Tags: google-chrome-extension, supabase

I am currently working on a Chrome extension that relies on a web application for user login. The web application leverages Supabase and the Google provider for user authentication. I have successfully implemented the authentication process within the browser, but I am encountering challenges in sharing the authentication status between the Chrome extension and the web application.

In Supabase, user authentication results in the storage of authentication-related data in the local storage. I am seeking a solution to effectively share this authentication status between the web application and the Chrome extension.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this. Specifically, I am looking for a way to access and share the authentication status stored in the local storage between the web application and the Chrome extension.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Maybe it's as simple as this, but read below if this doesn't work. I'm really only familiar with cookie based sessions.

```
const supabase = createClient(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
  {
    global: {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${supabaseAccessToken}`,
      },
    },
  }
);
```

This is possible because I have managed to do it with cookie-based auth tokens. At the end of the day, you have to tell `createClient` it can pull auth information from a `storage` object. *Normally* this would be something like local storage, but you're going to fake it.

1. Pass your local storage auth data to your extension with [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage).
2. Create a "Storage Adapter" that the supabase client will use to access this auth data
3. Pass that storage adapter in the [auth.storage](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/blob/master/src/lib/types.ts#L38) key of the `createClient` options.

In your service worker, something like this might get you to POC. It is unsophisticated and incomplete, but it might give you enough to start setting some breakpoints and see what's what under the hood.

```
import { parseSupabaseCookie } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-shared";

// Pass this from your web app to the extension with sendMessage
const myAuthTokenFromLocalStorage = "...";

const storageAdapter = {
  getItem: async (name: string) =>
    JSON.stringify(parseSupabaseCookie(decodeURIComponent(myAuthTokenFromLocalStorage))),

  setItem: async (name: string, value: string) => {
    // I don't think we actually care about this, but typescript will. 
    // I suppose you may want something if you allow your extension to refresh the token.
    return null;
  },

  removeItem: async (name: string) => {
    // I don't think we actually care about this, but typescript will. 
    // You may need to implement something here to prevent createClient from 
    // bugging out if it tries to delete an "invalid" auth token. I dunno.
  },
};

const supabaseClient = await createClient<Database>(
  SUPABASE_URL,
  SUPABASE_KEY,
  {
    auth: {
      storage: storageAdapter,
      flowType: "pkce", // uhh maybe you want this? Maybe you can exclude? I truly don't know
      autoRefreshToken: false,
      detectSessionInUrl: false,
      persistSession: true,
    },
  }
);
```

I'm not sure how much of `parseSupabaseCookie(decodeURIComponent(...))` is necessary for you. It may be specific to the cookie based storage. The important thing is that you need to return a stringified [Session](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/67eb6169aeb1b1a42d7c7e7cbf6336aef79e55de/src/lib/types.ts#L179) object.

I arrived at my solution by digging through source code at  https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers and https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js in addition to quite a lot of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

This question was really helpful. So I wanted to put the `typescript` version that worked for me in the `chrome-extension`

```
// To fetch items from storage
export const getLocalStorage = async (key: string): Promise<any> =>(await chrome.storage.local.get(key))[key];

// To remove storage key from the chrome storage
export const removeLocalStorage = async (key: string): Promise<void> => await chrome.storage.local.remove(key);

// For setting storage
export  const setLocalStorage = async (dataObject: any): Promise<void> => await chrome.storage.local.set(dataObject)


const storageAdapter = {
  getItem: async (name: string) => {
    return (await getLocalStorage(name));
  },

  setItem: async (name: string, value: string) => {
    return await setLocalStorage({ [name]: value });
  },

  removeItem: async (name: string) => {
    return await removeLocalStorage(name);
  },
};

const options = {
  auth: {
    debug: true,
    persistSession: true,
    storage: storageAdapter,
  }
};

const supabaseClient: supabase.SupabaseClient = supabase
  .createClient(
    'SUPABASE_URL',
    'SUPABASE_ANON_KEY',
    options
  );
```

then setting the session with

```
const userSession = await supabaseClient.auth.setSession({
      refresh_token,
      access_token,
    });
```